# Show 1st Image from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I need to show only first image from an array now I got all images but I need only 1st image shown.

Here is the code:

```
<?php $gallery = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), CHEFSCUISINE_RECIPE_PREFIX . 'gallery', true );   ?> 
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail( $recipe ) ) { ?>
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $recipe, 'full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) ); ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
                

    <?php foreach ( $gallery as $id => $src ) : ?>
      
      <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $src ); ?>" alt="gallery-image">
      
    <?php endforeach; } ?>
```

Comment: Add this to your code: print_r($gallery); and post the results here in the comments

Answer (score 0):

```
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail( $recipe ) ) { ?>
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $recipe, 'full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) ); ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
            

            <?php  ?>
             
             <img src="<?php echo $gallery[0] ; ?>" alt="gallery-image">
           
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You might want to make sure that the `$gallery` is not empty before using `$gallery[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

if the gallery array is not empty and then use the `reset()` function to retrieve the first image from the array. It will only display the first image if the gallery array is not empty.

```
$gallery = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), CHEFSCUISINE_RECIPE_PREFIX . 'gallery', true );

if ( has_post_thumbnail( $recipe ) ) {
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $recipe, 'full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) );
} else {
    // Check if the gallery array is not empty and get the first image
    if ( ! empty( $gallery ) ) {
        $first_image = reset( $gallery );
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $first_image ); ?>" alt="gallery-image">
        <?php
    }
}
```